# Select colors of Android app on installation

Tags: java, android, parameters, apk, processing

I've been doing an animated background for android using Processing (APDE, Java). The problem is that currently the background can only have hard-coded colors because in order to have the background, you have to install the apk.

I've searched if it is possible to pass parameters when installing an apk or between apps, but I didn't find anything suitable.

If I have to, I can do a secondary app to select the colors, but I don't know if you can do a color selector natively or in the actual background app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand your problem exactly! i think u need to change the background colour remotely like from another device. if so you can do it by passing colour code as JSON

```
{  
"Colorcode": {  
    "colorid":       "#fffff",   

}
```

}

make this type of JSON structure, put it in a server and fetch it to your app, set colorid as your required colour.so whenever you change this colourid from your server it will affect on your app